# Came up with serialization algorithm for strings, but only works for words that are < 10 letters long.

Tags: python, algorithm, serialization, deserialization

So I had a question about a serialization algorithm I just came up with it, wanted to know if it already exists and if there's a better version out there.

So we know normal algorithms use a delimiter and join words in a list, but then you have to look through the whole word for existence of the delimiter, escape, etc, or make the serialization algorithm not robust. I thought a more intuitive approach would be to use higher level languages like Python where `len()` is `O(1)` and prepend that to each word. So for example this code I attached.

Wouldn't this be faster because instead of going through every letter of every word we instead just go through every word? And then deserialization we don't have to look through every character to find the delimiter, we can just skip directly to the end of each word.

The only problem I see is that double digit sizes would cause problems, but I'm sure there's a way around that I haven't found yet.

It was suggested to me that [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) are similar to this idea, but I haven't understood why yet.

```
def serialize(list_o_words):
    return ''.join(str(len(word)) + word for word in list_o_words)

def deserialize(serialized_list_o_words):
    index = 0
    deserialized_list = []
    while index < len(serialized_list_o_words):
        word_length = int(serialized_list_o_words[index])
        next_index = index + word_length + 1
        deserialized_list.append(serialized_list_o_words[index+1:next_index])
        index = next_index
    return deserialized_list
serialized_list = "some,comma,separated,text".split(",")

print(serialize(serialized_list))
print(deserialize(serialize(serialized_list)) == serialized_list)
```

Essentially, I want to know how I can handle double digit lengths.

Comment: Length-prefixed strings are a pretty standard data type, not just for persistence formats and network protocols, but even for internal storage. There are many variations—the length could be 1 byte, 2 bytes, 4 bytes, a variable-length binary int, or an ASCII int. There are advantages and disadvantages to all of them.

Comment: Meanwhile, "faster" than what exactly, and what's going to be faster? Any persistence format requires you to read or write every byte in the data. Sure, if you know you want to "read 17 bytes" instead of "read until the next comma", that's a bit more efficient—but reading 8K at a time into a buffer and processing that buffer is a whole lot more efficient than either one.

Comment: Also, length-prefixed strings solve some problems, but create others. For example, you don't have to worry about quoting or escaping delimiters. On the other hand, if you jump into the middle of a stream—or get out of sync because of an error—with comma-separated values you just read to the next unescaped comma and you're fine; with length-prefixed strings, you're going to treat an arbitrary byte or whatever as a length and just get even farther out of sync without ever recovering.

Comment: You might be interested in djb's (very short) paper on [netstrings](https://cr.yp.to/proto/netstrings.txt), a length-prefixed format that has variable-length but still human-editable strings, and a tiny bit of redundancy to handle the sync problem, and is still dead simple. (A lot easier to understand than protocol buffers, if you're struggling there.)

Comment: Wow the curse of SO. I post a genuine perfectly formatted and created question on here, with what I've tried, what I know, and a clear request for information. Already two downvotes probably people just saw the word halp and assumed the question was shit. Thanks @abanert for being the only person to help me, I'm not so familiar with network address syntax and other stuff so I didn't know that. I'll look into netstrings, sounds promising.

Comment: Also edited the question as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: The title may well be the reason for most of the downvotes—but it really is misleading; you should edit it. But I think the bigger problem is that you aren't asking a specific question. If you _have_ a specific question (like how you can make your code handle strings >10 chars without wasting bytes for short strings, or how to set up and run a performance benchmark for two different simple serialization libraries you built, or …), edit the question to be about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many variations on length-prefixed strings, but the key bits come down to how you store the length.

You're deserializing the lengths as a single-character ASCII number, which means you can only handle lengths from 0 to 9. (You don't actually test that on the serialize size, so you can generate garbage, but let's forget that.)

---

So, the obvious option is to use 2 characters instead of 1. Let's add in a bit of error handling while we're at it; the code is still pretty easy:

```
def _len(word):
    s = format(len(word), '02')
    if len(s) != 2:
        raise ValueError(f"Can't serialize {s}; it's too long")
    return s

def serialize(list_o_words):
    return ''.join(_len(word) + word for word in list_o_words)

def deserialize(serialized_list_o_words):
    index = 0
    deserialized_list = []
    while index+1 < len(serialized_list_o_words):
        word_length = int(serialized_list_o_words[index:index+2])
        next_index = index + word_length + 2
        deserialized_list.append(serialized_list_o_words[index+2:next_index])
        index = next_index
    return deserialized_list
```

---

But now you can't handle strings >99 characters.

Of course you can keep adding more digits for longer strings, but if you think "I'm never going to need a 100,000-character string"… you are going to need it, and then you'll have a zillion old files in the 5-digit format that aren't compatible with the new 6-digit format.

Also, this wastes a lot of bytes. If you're using 5-digit lengths, `s` encodes as `00000s`, which is 6x as big as the original value.

---

You can stretch things a lot farther by using binary lengths instead of ASCII. Now, with two bytes, we can handle lengths up to 65535 instead of just 99. And if you go to four or eight bytes, that *might* actually be big enough for all your strings ever. Of course this only works if you're storing `bytes` rather than Unicode strings, but that's fine; you probably needed to encode your strings for persistence anyway. So:

```
def _len(word):
    # already raises an exception for lengths > 65535
    s = struct.pack('>H', len(word))

def serialize(list_o_words):
    utfs8 = (word.encode() for word in list_o_words)
    return b''.join(_len(utf8) + utf8 for utf8 in utfs8)
```

Of course this isn't very human-readable or -editable; you need to be comfortable in a hex editor to replace a string in a file this way.

---

Another option is to delimit the lengths. This may sound like a step backward—but it still gives us all the benefits of knowing the length in advance. Sure, you have to "read until comma", but you don't have to worry about escaped or quoted commas the way you do with CSV files, and if you're worried about performance, it's going to be much faster to read a buffer of 8K at a time and chunk through it with some kind of C loop (whether that's slicing, or `str.find`, barely matters by comparison) than to actually read either until comma or just two bytes.

This also has the benefit of solving the sync problem. With delimited values, if you come in mid-stream, or get out of sync because of an error, it's no big deal; just read until the next unescaped delimiter and worst-case you missed a few values. With length-prefixed values, if you're out of sync, you're reading arbitrary characters and treating them as a length, which just throws you even more out of sync. The [netstring](https://cr.yp.to/proto/netstrings.txt) format is a minor variation on this idea, with a tiny bit more redundancy to make sync problems easier to detect/recover from.

---

Going back to binary lengths, there are all kinds of clever tricks for encoding variable-length numbers. Here's one idea, in pseudocode:

```
if the current byte is < hex 0x80 (128):
    that's the length
else: 
    add the low 7 bits of the current byte
    plus 128 times (recursively process the next byte)
```

Now you can handle short strings with just 1 byte of length, but if a 5-billion-character string comes along, you can handle that too.

Of course this is even less human-readable than fixed binary lengths.

---

And finally, if you ever want to be able to store other kinds of values, not just strings, you probably want a format that uses a "type code". For example, use `I` for 32-bit int, `f` for 64-bit float, `D` for `datetime.datetime`, etc. Then you can use `s` for strings <256 characters with a 1-byte length, `S` for strings <65536 characters with a 2-byte length, `z` for string <4B characters with a 4-byte length, and `Z` for unlimited strings with a complicated variable-int length (or maybe null-terminated strings, or maybe an 8-byte length is close enough to unlimited—after all, nobody's ever going to want more than 640KB in a computer…).